# How to force Xorg to use integrated video (ASPEED) instead of my Tesla K20?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, cuda

I'm trying to get my brand new server up and running for gpgpu with 14.04LTS, but I'm having issues with the graphics drivers. If I install the CUDA Toolkit, it also installs regular nvidia drivers and the computer tries to use the Tesla card for graphics processing. This results in failure to load GLX (not exactly sure why). Is there a way to force the system to use the on board graphics chip (ASPEED) or maybe just the Nouveau drivers for graphical stuff and just use the Tesla for gpu computing?  Maybe in the xorg.conf?